# Prove that set $\{\wedge, \vee \}$ is not functionally complete

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How to prove that set $\{\wedge, \vee \}$ is not functional complete?

I tried to do it like this, I tried to show that $\neg x$ couldnt be received by $\wedge$ and $\vee$.

I take function $\neg x = \phi(x)$.
Here I want to show that $\neg x \neq \phi(x)$. And after that I use induction.

Step $k=0$: $x = \phi(x)$, if $x=0$ then $\phi(0) = 0$. After that $\neg x \neq x$, because $0 \neq 1$.

Step $k = 1$: $\phi(x) = x \wedge x$ or $\phi(x) = x \vee x$ and here I have problems. I dont know what to do next...

Comment: Your induction might go better if you try to show that neither the negation function nor the constant-false function can be expressed using only the variable $x$ and the connectives $\land$ and $\lor$. (This is essentially the answer by Bram28 but using one variable instead of two.)

Comment: It just occurred to me that it's easier yet to prove by induction that, with one variable $x$, the only function you can represent with $\land$ and $\lor$ is the identity function. That is, any expression you write using $x,\land,\lor$ is equivalent to just $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of focusing on a function that takes just one variable, it may be a little easier to think of a function with two variables, just like the $\land$ and $\lor$.

In particular, show (using induction!) that using $\land $ and $\lor$ alone, you cannot capture any function of two variables that returns False when both variables are True, for example $\neg (p \land q)$.